# How do I say: 'searching online' or 'online searching'?

Tags: word-order

Meaning someone was looking for information, not noun, but a verb.

*You spent some time **searching online** yesterday*

*You spent some time **online searching** yesterday*

Which one is correct? Also, can I just use *searching* meaning online search and throw *online* out? Is it common to use it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions are syntactically fine - it's just a matter of "nuance" regarding which aspect - the "location" *(online)*, or the "activity" *(searching)* you think is more important. If you think both aspects are equally important, it makes absolutely no difference which version you choose. Otherwise, specify the more important one first.

Compare with *Tony is **here asking / asking here** for help with English*, where exactly the same principle applies (in each case, the *second* term is "less important", and could thus more easily be discarded without significantly affecting meaning).